# jbehave: disable all reporting

Tags: java, jbehave

I'm using jbehave for some BDD style testing through ant and junit. I'd like to disable all sorts of reports generated to a file when running jbehave, as I'm not using any of those at the moment. I'm initialising my test runner with the following configuration:

```
@RunWith(JUnitReportingRunner.class)
public abstract class StepsRunner extends JUnitStories {

    private Configuration configuration;

    public StepsRunner() {
        super();
        configuration = new MostUsefulConfiguration();
        EmbedderControls embedderControls = configuredEmbedder()
                .embedderControls();
        embedderControls.doGenerateViewAfterStories(false);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This successfully prevents any jbehave report views from being generated. However, I still get one single file generated at `$PWD/target/jbehave/storyDurations.props`.

Can I prevent jbehave from generating any files, including this one? If that's not possible, is there a way to configure jbehave such that those files aren't created in `$PWD/target`?

For what it's worth, my ant file is running the jbehave tests as if they were standard junit tests using the `<junit/>` task (I can include a simplified version of the build file, but there's nothing magic happening there).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with my current solution (alternative/better solutions still welcome!).

Looking at the jbehave source code, the incriminated file at `$PWD/target/jbehave/storyDurations.props` is being written by [StoryManager](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/core/org/jbehave/core/embedder/StoryManager.html). It uses the location returned by `configuration.storyReporterBuilder().outputDirectory()`:

```
protected void writeStoryDurations(Collection<RunningStory> runningStories) {
    // collect story durations and cancel any outstanding execution which is
    // not done before returning
    [...]
    write(storyDurations, "storyDurations.props");
}

private void write(Properties p, String name) {
    File outputDirectory = configuration.storyReporterBuilder()
            .outputDirectory();
    try {
        outputDirectory.mkdirs();
        Writer output = new FileWriter(new File(outputDirectory, name));
        p.store(output, this.getClass().getName());
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thus, it's possible to force our report/output files to be generated to another path by providing a custom `StoryReporterBuilder` to the configuration, like this:

```
public StepsRunner() {
    super();
    configuration = new MostUsefulConfiguration();
    final File outputDir = new File(System.getProperty("jbehave.output.dir"));
    configuration.useStoryReporterBuilder( new StoryReporterBuilder() {
        @Override
        public File outputDirectory()
        {
            return outputDir;
        }
    });
}
```

Now all jbehave output files will be written inside the folder pointed to by the `jbehave.output.dir` system property.

From then on, it's simple enough to pass the actual value for the jbehave output directory location from ant to junit by setting the `jbehave.output.dir` system property in the ant target:

```
<junit>
  <sysproperty key="jbehave.output.dir" value="/tmp/jbehave/output/" />
  <batchtest>
     ...
  </batchtest>
</junit>
```